# Validation failed: Email is invalid, Password can't be blank (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rake

I decided on an exercise following the commits from this [github repo](https://github.com/mrmicahcooper/micah), and am stuck at a failed validation. When I run 'rake' I get the following back:

```
Scenario: Admin signs in            # features/admin.feature:2
  Given the following admin:        # features/step_definitions/fabrication_steps.rb:19
    | email    | dl@example.com |
    | password | password       |
    Validation failed: Email is invalid, Password can't be blank (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
    ./features/step_definitions/fabrication_steps.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    ./features/step_definitions/fabrication_steps.rb:6:in `with_ivars'
    ./features/step_definitions/fabrication_steps.rb:20:in `/^the following ([^"]*):$/'
    features/admin.feature:3:in `Given the following admin:'
```

I cloned the author's repo, reverted to the commit I am currently stuck, and noticed running 'rake' first produced the following output (which did not occur for mine):

```
NOTICE: CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "admins_id_seq" for serial column "admins.id"
NOTICE: CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "admins_pkey" for table "admins"
NOTICE: CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "posts_id_seq" for serial column "posts.id"
NOTICE: CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "posts_pkey" for table "posts"
/home/dl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby -S bundle exec cucumber --profile default
Using the default profile...
```

I tried the following commands, also to no avail:

```
rake db:create
rake db:setup
rake db:test:prepare
rake
```

Other potential solutions seem not to fit either. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an issue in the model that reflects the difference between rails 3 (the original repo) and rails 4 (me).

I made some changes to my admin model and controller, to handle mass-assignment.

If anyone comes across this and wants further info, just let me know.